# R random forest : data (x) has 0 rows

Tags: r, random-forest

I am using `randomForest` function from randomForest package to find the most important variable:
my dataframe is called urban and my response variable is revenue which is numeric.

```
urban.random.forest <- randomForest(revenue ~ .,y=urban$revenue, data = urban, ntree=500,    keep.forest=FALSE,importance=TRUE,na.action = na.omit)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : data (x) has 0 rows
```

on the source code it is related to `x` variable:

```
n <- nrow(x)
p <- ncol(x)
if (n == 0) 
stop("data (x) has 0 rows")
```

but I cannot understand what is `x`.

Comment: You are mixing the formula and the default methods. If you pass a formula to `randomForest` you shouldn't pass the `y` value again, because then the function assumes that the formula is the `x` value and things go wrong.

Comment: I removed y=urban$revenue but the error still exists:    Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : data (x) has 0 rows

Comment: I have a new error also: In addition: Warning message:
In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression? Although my response variable has 58 unique values     length(unique(urban$revenue))# ==58

Comment: The error is probably in your data, because your line works fine with iris data `urban.random.forest <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, ntree=500,    keep.forest = FALSE,importance = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved that. I had some columns that all their values were NA or the same. I dropped them and it went  OK. my columns classes were character, numeric and factor.

```
 candidatesnodata.index <- c()
 for (j in (1 : ncol(dataframe)))   {

   if (    is.numeric(dataframe[ ,j])  &  length(unique(as.numeric(dataframe[ ,j]))) == 1      )
     {candidatesnodata.index <- append(candidatesnodata.index,j)}
                                }

dataframe <- dataframe[ , - candidatesnodata.index]
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar problem and it stemmed from the fact that I was passing in a string version of the call

```
y ~ x1 + .... xn
```

to the formula argument of the randomForest call. The simple fix was to cast the input to as.Formula().

I hope this saves anyone some time!