# R: randomForest error message

Tags: r, random-forest

Trying to run Random Forest on a data set that has 400~ samples, and about 360 variables in data frame df:

[image: Data frame preview]

I'm trying to use the the variables (`s10`, `s100`, etc etc) to predict the Genotype. This is the code I'm using:

```
rf <-randomForest(Genotype ~ ., data = df, importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE)
```

but I keep getting the error message:

```
Error in if (n == 0) stop("data (x) has 0 rows") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609010/r-random-forest-data-x-has-0-rows) helps

Answer (score 0):

First, don't name your objects the same as R functions (ie., "df"). Second, try a non-formula interface to randomForest. Let's where that gets you.

```
( rf <-randomForest(y=my.df[,"Genotype"], x=my.df[,2:ncol(my.df)], importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE) )
```

Comment: Yep! that worked. Thanks! Still not sure why the formula method didn't work though...